# why does my html image area map with an on-hover pop-up only work in Google Chrome?

Tags: html, css

here is a bit of my code:

```
<div class="table1"> 

<img src="images/table.jpg" width="940" height="818" alt="Comparative table"    usemap="tablemap">

<map name="tablemap" >

<FIX1>
  <area href="page1.html" shape="rect" coords="1,116,105,184" alt="item1">
</FIX1>

</map>

</div>
```

and the CSS for that:

```
.table1 {
    width:940px;
    height:818px;
    margin-left:-10px;
}


FIX1:hover{
    content:url(images/guppie.jpg);
    display:block;
    width:506px;
    height:506px;
    z-index:110;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-701px;
    margin-left:105px;
}
```

I was battling to get it working so I used my own tag. Clearly I'm no expert.

Any help of any kind would be greatly appreciated. I'm keen to learn anything I can so please don't be afraid to criticize.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have some serious trouble getting that to work, as DOM support for image maps is rather quirky on many browsers.

You could start by dumping you **FIX1** element and assigning an ID to the **area**:

```
<area id="FIX1" href="page1.html" shape="rect" coords="1,116,105,184" alt="item1">
```

Then you can use that id to reference the element from your CSS:

```
#FIX1:hover{
    ....
}
```

Anyway, I'd rather use a specific DOM manipulation library like JQuery

Comment: Thank you! much appreciated, i'll keep you updated on my progress...:)